# Extjs 6: What's the best practice to handle repeated configuration

Tags: javascript, extjs

When I define a view class, I have to set a lot of repeated configs for child components.

Here is an example:

```
Ext.define('TEST.view.transaction.TransactionEditor', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    ...
    items: [{
        ...
        labelWidth:80,
        width: 230,
        tdAttrs: { style: 'padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;' },
        ...
    },{
        ...
        labelWidth:80,
        width: 230,
        tdAttrs: { style: 'padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;' }
        ...
    },
    ...
    ],
    ...
}
```

As you can see, the labelWidth, width and style are repeated several times. I want to use some constants or variables instead of these magic numbers. What is the proper way to do it in EXTJS?

---

UPDATE:
The following two methods do not work well.

1. Using defaults is working for labelWidth and width, but does not work for tdAttrs.
2. By using the initComponent method, the component stopped displaying.

   initComponent:function() {

   ```
       var tdAttrs = { style: 'padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;' };
       Ext.apply(this,{
           items:[{
               tdAttrs:tdAttrs
           }]}
       );
       this.callParent(arguments);
   },
   ```

---

UPDATE2:

I solved the issue of tdAttrs not working using method 1. tdAttrs should be put under layout config instead of defaults. I do not know why, but here is the working code.

```
layout: {
    type: 'table',
    // The total column count must be specified here
    columns: 4,
    tdAttrs: { style: 'padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;' }
},
defaults:{
    labelWidth:70,
    width: 210
},
items: [/* include child components here */
    {
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

For the initComponent method, I still do not know how to do it. Please help.

Comment: I have updated my answer regarding initComponent, hope it helps. You have to put [`tdAttrs`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Table-cfg-tdAttrs) into the layout because they are in the docs in `Ext.layout.container.Table` (`layout:'table'`), and these are defined via the layout subconfig. Every config you find in a `Ext.layout.container.XYZ` (`layout:'xyz'`) have to be defined in the layout subconfig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various [DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself) approaches in ExtJS.

If the values are repeated in *all* applicable sub-items of a container, you can use [`defaults`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-cfg-defaults):

```
Ext.define('TEST.view.transaction.TransactionEditor', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    defaults:{
        labelWidth:80,
        width: 230,
        tdAttrs: { style: 'padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;' },
        queryMode:'local' // EXAMPLE: this will be added to all fields, but only have effect in combos!
    },
```

If they aren't, you could define variables:

```
var labelWidth=80,
...
Ext.define('TEST.view.transaction.TransactionEditor', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    ...
        labelWidth:labelWidth,
```

but this is **not recommended**, because you then have a clutter of *global* variables. It's better to put the whole items definition into initComponent, because then, the variables are kept inside the scope:

```
Ext.define('TEST.view.transaction.TransactionEditor', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    initComponent:function() {
        var labelWidth = 80,
            width = 230;
        Ext.apply(this,{
            items:[{
                    ...
                    labelWidth:labelWidth,
                    width: width,
                    ...
                },{
                    ...
                    labelWidth:labelWidth,
                    width: width,
                    ...
                },
                ...
                ],
                ...
            }
        });
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
```

or, if all of them are of a certain xtype, but across multiple containers, to derive a special `xtype`, so instead of

```
items:[{
   xtype:'textfield',
   labelWidth:125,
},{
   xtype:'textfield',
   labelWidth:125,
},{
   xtype:'textfield',
   labelWidth:125,
```

use

```
items:[{
   xtype:'mytextfield'
},{
   xtype:'mytextfield'
},{
   xtype:'mytextfield'
```

with mytextfield being defined as

```
Ext.define('MyTextField',{
    extend:'Ext.form.field.Text',
    xtype:'mytextfield',
    labelWidth:125,
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks !! This is very helpful.

Comment: The first method works for labelWidth and width but not for tdAttrs. For the initComponent method, where does the argument variable come from?

Comment: After using the initComponent method, my TransactionEditor stopped displaying. The console had no error but the following warnings:  [W] [Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading 'Ext.layout.container.Table'; consider adding Ext.require('Ext.layout.container.Table') above Ext.onReady
bootstrap.js:849 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: @Alex initComponent has to contain the line `this.callParent(arguments);`, if you don't have it, nothing will be shown.

Comment: Yes it's there but still does not show anything. I edited my question to show my code. Please check.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean using initComponent method. Originally, I left the items config outside of the initComponent method and I did not put xtype and other configs into the applying object. Thank you.